# IsPostback not working in gridview asp:HyperLinkField

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

Here is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gridv" AutoGenerateColumns="true" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:HyperLinkField runat="server" HeaderText="GetStudentInfo" SortExpression="GetStudentInfo" DataTextField="StudentName" NavigateUrl="StudentManagement2.aspx" />
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="ClickPostback" />     
</form>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack) return;
    gridv.DataSource = GetStudent();
    gridv.DataBind();
}
```

When i click on the hyperlink on GridView - Postback is **always false**:

[image]

However when i click the Button Postback variable is True:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post back occurs when a form gets submitted back to the server.

Hyperlinks are used for navigation, not form submission.  So by default they redirect the user to a new page and do not post any information back to the server, which is why the post back is showing as false.

In your example the hyperlink has a NavigateUrl property which is where you are telling the application to "go to this page". It's not sending any information to the server for processing.

Buttons however where designed to post information back to the server, which is why it is showing true.